# Arduino IDE Crashes When Attempting to Save Sketch

Tags: ide, arduino

I recently updated Ubuntu (15.04) and ever since the update my Arduino IDE crashes when attempting to save a sketch. Last night I removed and reinstalled the IDE and I am still having the same issue. It seems like it's having trouble finding the "sketch" folder. Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? I am in the same boat at the moment.

Comment: dibs-No, nothing as of yet. I'm currently saving all my sketches to a word document so I can copy 'n paste if/when the issue is ever fixed. Please let me know if you find anything out?

Answer (score 0):

I think this topic will solve your problem: [Ubuntu V15.04 Save As selection crashes IDE](http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=318520.0).

Shortly, Open a command terminal, navigate to the arduino directory where the arduino shell script is located (like /arduino-1.6.3), then type these lines:

```
 export JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS=""
./arduino
```